# How to enable DNS over HTTPS (DoH) in group policy on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, dns, windows-11, group-policy

I am trying to enable DNS over HTTPS on my personal Windows 11 (Build 22621.1105) machine (Lenovo ThinkPad). I am the only user account on this machine (MS Account, Admin).

In the settings for the DNS (e.g. [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-tcp-ip-settings-bd0a07af-15f5-cd6a-363f-ca2b6f391ace)) I can specify the preferred/alternate DNS (I am using Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1/1.0.0.1) -- but the DNS over HTTPS combobox is disabled (and showing "Off").
At the top of these settings it shows a text like "***Some of these settings are disabled or managed by your organization**" (translated from German):

[image: screenshot]

So I checked the Group Policy and indeed under "**Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Network/DNS Client**" the "**Configure DNS over HTTPS (DoH) name resolution**" policy is enabled and configured as "**Prohibit DoH**". When I change this configuration or disable the policy, then after reopening Group Policy it shows "Prohibit DoH" again. In contrast, I can (permanently) change other policies, so for whatever reason I am not able to change this particular policy.

So my question: How to change this policy and/or what's the reason I can't change it?

I am thankful for any help!

**Update:**

I also tried the [proposed solution from *harrymc*'s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1764668/1766840) (adding a DWORD `EnableAutoDoh` with value `2` under the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters` registry key). As a result the DNS client is not able to perform name resolution, so it seems that this registry entry enforces DoH, but the group policy doesn't allow it and therefore the DNS client will fail to resolve a name. Therefore I am quite sure that the problem is that I cannot change the above mentioned group policy.

**Update 2:**

I found out that the policy is stored in the registry under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient` as a DWORD `DoHPolicy` with value 1. When I delete the value I can enable DoH via the drop-down in the settings and it also works. But when I restart the machine or try to change this policy in `gpedit.msc` it will create the value again and set it to 1. So some process seems to set this value ... I will investigate this further when I have a bit more time and post this here when I've found the cause (if nobody is faster than me ;)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, so here for anyone who also stumbles across the same or a similar one:

As already posted in my question (update) I was not able to change the "**Configure DNS over HTTPS (DoH) name resolution**" group policy (which was set to "**Prohibit DoH**"). After some investigations it seemed that some process sets this policy to "Prohibit DoH" on startup and every time after it is changed via the *Group Policy Editor* (`gpedit.msc`).

The setting of this policy is stored as a registry value with name `DoHPolicy` under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient`. So I used [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to track which processes access or more specifically **set** this value and found out that right after the value is set or deleted via the *Group Policy Editor* a process named `vpnagent.exe` (creates and) sets the value to '1' ([which corresponds to "**Prohibit DoH**"](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_11_2022&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.DNSClient::DNS_Doh)).

The service `vpnagent.exe` is part of the VPN client *Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Agent*. I don't know why it insists on setting the group policy, but the only solution I found to my problem (aside from uninstalling the software) is to stop the service before changing the policy or to delete the registry value via `regedit.exe` (but this has to be done after each reboot).

Answer (score 0):

"DNS over HTTPS" drop-down should normally not be disabled.

**Enabling DoH via Group Policies**

- Run the Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Navigate to
  *Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates >
  Network > DNS Client section*
- Enable the policy "Configure DNS over HTTPS (DoH) name resolution"

**Enabling DoH in the Windows 10 Registry**

- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters`
- Create a new DWORD named `EnableAutoDoh` with a value of 2
- Reboot
- Change primary and alternate DNS servers,
  in the adapter Properties, at
  "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)".
  You may use either Cloudflare, Google or Quad9.
- Reboot again.

You may find more information in the article
[What DNS over HTTPS (DoH) Is & How to Enable in Windows 10](https://blog.netwrix.com/2022/10/11/dns-over-https/).

If none of the methods work, then the problem is more profound.

Comment: You didn't read my question, did you? The link in my question shows exactly the same procedure, but as described, this doesn't work for me because the "DNS over HTTPS" drop-down is disabled. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry - I jumped the gun. I rewrote my answer and hope one of the two methods will work.

Comment: Thanks for taking time! Unfortunately neither of them works. Interestingly when adding the registry key as proposed in your second method, the DNS client will fail (verified via e.g. "ping example.org"), so it seems that the registry key really forces DoH, but the group policy doesn't allow it, which will result in a failure. So my problem is that I can't change this particular group policy. ... I guess I shouldn't have stayed with the preinstalled Win11 but reinstalled it by myself after buying the notebook ...

Comment: Strange, what happens when you try to change the policy?

Comment: Group Policy Editor lets me change the policy (or at least there is no error and the UI shows that it is changed), but after reopening Group Policy Editor it shows "Prohibit DoH" again.

Comment: Okay that gave me an idea and I found something: apparently this policy is stored under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient` as a DWORD `DoHPolicy`. In my case this value is set to 1. When I delete the value, I can enable DoH via the drop-down in the settings, and it also works. But when I restart the machine or try to change this policy in `gpedit.msc` it will create the value again and set it to 1. Really strange indeed ... I will investigate this further and update my question when I've found the cause.

Comment: You should be setting `DoHPolicy` to the value `2` - [link](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_11_2022&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.DNSClient::DNS_Doh). The value `1` means "Prohibit DoH".

Comment: Yes I now that, but my problem was that I was not able to change the value, because it was overwritten right after I changed it. Anyway, I've now found the cause of this, see my answer. Thanks for your help!